# Can I ask this question on askubuntu?

Tags: support, migration

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/944862/disconnet-internet-at-specific-time-in-ubuntu-12-04?noredirect=1#comment1286913_944862) here but there is not much attention to that question. Since my question directly consults Ubuntu and so I think that I should as this question on askubuntu.

While searching about my question on net I found few related(not exactly what I'm asking) question on askubuntu.

Kindly tell me, should I ask that same question here on askubuntu or not.

Comment: I would ask that here, your question is about software to perform a task on Ubuntu that is on topic here.

Comment: You indeed can if you want, but cross-posting is not allowed, so after you have deleted your question on Super User you can re-ask it here

Comment: Thank you sir @markkirby.

Comment: Thank you sir @kos.

Comment: Don't ask to ask, ask!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your question is about something that runs on Ubuntu, Ubuntu configuration, or basically anything else about Ubuntu, it is on-topic here. Unless it is about an [EOL release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), then it isn't on-topic here, or necessarily, anywhere. Although questions on software recommendations and windows replacement software might get better results on: [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

For more information on things which are on-topic here please read: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Questions about software recommendations or windows replacement software is better asked on: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/